# How does Core Data optional attribute of entity work?

Tags: ios, sqlite, cocoa-touch, core-data

I’m trying to set an entity attribute to be not null by setting it to be none-optional.

But when I assign the attribute nil in test case, it reports no error or exception and the test succeeded. And by the way, how can I make sure this attribute is not optional with unit testing?

```
Baby *baby = [self.babyModel createWithName:nil];
XCTAssertNil(baby.name);
```

And when I check the schema of the table in sqlite, it doesn’t set it to be not null. Does that mean this constraint is guaranteed by core data stack instead of sqlite?

Answer (score 1):

When you set a core data entity attribute to be non optional, you will get a crash when trying to save the context.  You can have the object with nil non optional attributes until you save, at that point it is braking the constraint for the database.

Your test should fail if you take out the XCTAssertNil and replace it by saving the context for which you used to create baby.

Either way, I am not sure what you are trying to test with the case above.  Are you testing the createWithName: function on babyModel? Are you trying to test that createWithName: does not allow creation of Baby object with no name?  If you answer what code path you are exactly trying to test, I can help you write a more appropriate test.

Comment: Thanks. Does that mean the optional setting will take effect during context saving? Yes, I'm testing createWithName: method of BabyModel and wish it does not allow empty name.

Comment: The optional setting is a constraint on the database, it will not allow you to save invalid data.  For your api, createWithName:, What do you expect it to do when you pass a nil name.  Should it crash the app?  Should it populate with an empty String?

Comment: I need to make sure the Optional setting is unchecked. And when it receive empty name as parameter, invalid entity is not created, and notify invoker of createWithName:. The schema of the baby table does not say the name field should be no null when I check the database, that confused me.